# Color profile switches with random application launch

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, color

My color profile seems to be switching when I launch random application. It seems to be doing it every time I open Illustrator or VirtualBox. If I go into the color Profile setting it's on the same setting all the time.

The switch is between the normal "white" profile to a much cooler "blueish" profile. I'm on an early 2011 15" MBP with 16 gig ram and 10.8.1.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Yeah a i've the same thing when lauching a Valve game on a 2008 iMac. And I also saw the same thing a 2010 MBP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, seeing the same thing on an early 2011 MacBook Pro as well. It seems to happen when the display switches to the GeForce GT chip from the Intel integrated graphics.

It doesn't seem to be random -- I can get it to switch the colour palette back and forth by using gfxCardStatus, which switches the graphics modes. Integrated = goes to normal palette, GeForce = blueish.

Seems like Apple has buggered up the colour profile for the GeForce chip.

Edit: For what it's worth, logging out and back in seems to help.

Comment: yip, downloaded gfxCardStatus and I see what you are seeing. It must have been introduced in Lion. fyi, I just updated to 10.8.2 and it's still doing it.